# how to update gemfile to only install watir

Tags: ruby, bundler, watir

This is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'watir', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.0' 
gem 'watir-scroll'
gem 'cucumber'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'page-object'
gem 'require_all'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.53', '>= 2.53.1'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6.8', '>= 1.6.8.1'
gem 'webdriver-user-agent', '~> 7.1'
gem 'headless'
gem 'bundle', '~> 0.0.1'
gem 'appium_lib'
gem 'rake'
gem 'test-unit'
```

When I execute bundle install with this gemfile, I find watir-webdriver & commonwatir are installed.

I want to only want watir installed. 
I don't want watir-webdriver or commonwatir installed.

How should I edit my gemfile?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Try latest version of watir(https://rubygems.org/gems/watir/versions/6.8.4). Only runtime dependency for this is "selenium-webdriver".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watir v5.0 is the last version of Watir where it was a meta gem for Watir-Webdriver and Watir-Classic. This is where commonwatir and watir-webdriver gems are dependencies. To remove them and only use Watir(-Webdriver), update the Watir gem to be the current 6.x release.

In other words, change:

```
gem 'watir', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.0'
```

To:

```
gem 'watir', '~> 6.0'
```

You probably should also remove (or at least update) the Selenium-WebDriver requirement. The current version of Watir is not going to work with Selenium-WebDriver v2.x. Given that Watir will already require Selenium, I don't think you need it in your gem file.

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.53', '>= 2.53.1'
```

Comment: Thanks justin for your response. Like what I posted in your blog, I want to use visible locators. Is there anything else to modify in my gemfile? thx

Comment: Watir 6+ requires Selenium 3+ so you'd have to change or remove that line as well.

Comment: @edmond, I think these changes should allow the usage of the :visible locator. If it doesn't let me know.

Comment: Thank Titus and Justin for your prompt response. I updated my gems using bundle. However, updating to watir 6.0 raises an issues during executing scenarios. One issue thrown up is undefined method browser_name. `undefined method browser_name for :chrome:Symbol (NoMethodError)` Hence, I will roll back to watir 5.0. I will discuss with my team as to when we update to watir 6.0

Comment: Suggest posting the code where that error pops up as a separate question here.  If you got that when moving from 5.x to 6.0 then likely others will have the same issue.  So it would be good to resolve what is causing it, and how to correct the error.   (trying to troubleshoot that in the comments thread to this question is the wrong place for that)

Answer (score 0):

Both are runtime dependencies of the `watir` gem, so of course, they would be installed automatically.

> https://rubygems.org/gems/watir/versions/5.0.0
>
> Runtime Dependencies (2):
>
> commonwatir ~> 4
>
> watir-webdriver >= 0